# Telerik Radgridview comboboxcolumn and selectedindexchangedevent

Tags: telerik, radgridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Good days,
How can i create telerik radgridview combobox column and add listen selected indexchanged event  method of combobox?

Comment: If you are using silverlight controls in telerik, take a look into this : http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radgridview-columns-column-types-combobox-column.html

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using a GridTemplateColumn column containing a combo-box?